# QSharedMemory : Second process cannot attach

Tags: qt, shared-memory

I have 2 processes.

The first one creates a QSharedMemory, with a key.

The creation is successful, as no error is returned.

In the second process, I try and attach to the shared memory, having done `setKey()` with the same key name as the first process, and then try and `attach()` to the memory.

The `attach()` fails. Using `errorString()` on the shared memory, the following string is returned :

```
QSharedMemory::handle: doesn't exist
```

Platform is Windows.

What could I be missing here? Kindly advise, thanks.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the shared memory example?

http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/ipc-sharedmemory.html

Below are some code snippets from that example.

Here is what the first process does to put a buffer of "size" into the shared memory:

```
if (!sharedMemory.create(size)) {
    ui.label->setText(tr("Unable to create shared memory segment."));
    return;
}
sharedMemory.lock();
char *to = (char*)sharedMemory.data();
const char *from = buffer.data().data();
memcpy(to, from, qMin(sharedMemory.size(), size));
sharedMemory.unlock();
```

Here is what happens when the second process wants to access the shared memory:

```
if (!sharedMemory.attach()) {
    ui.label->setText(tr("Unable to attach to shared memory segment.\n" \
             "Load an image first."));
    return;
}

QBuffer buffer;
QDataStream in(&buffer);
QImage image;

sharedMemory.lock();
buffer.setData((char*)sharedMemory.constData(), sharedMemory.size());
buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadOnly);
in >> image;
sharedMemory.unlock();

sharedMemory.detach();
ui.label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
```

Note also that in the example, both processes must be running and still have their instance of QSharedMemory.  Here is how it is described in the documentation:

> Windows: QSharedMemory does not "own" the shared memory segment. When
>   all threads or processes that have an instance of QSharedMemory
>   attached to a particular shared memory segment have either destroyed
>   their instance of QSharedMemory or exited, the Windows kernel releases
>   the shared memory segment automatically.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have looked through the example, yes. In the first, I create the memory ( creation automatically implies an attach),with a size and a key. In the second process, I try and attach to the shared memory, using `setKey()` and `attach()`. The first process is running at the time. But I get that error, nonetheless.

Comment: I've successfully ran the example twice on two different window machines.  In the example, it doesn't call `setKey`.  It instead constructs the member variable `sharedMemory` with the same key in the `Dialog` constructor.  What happens when you run the example without editing it?

Comment: OK. I ran it without the `setKey()`, instead, I passed the name of the key in the constructor. Again, cannot attach to shared memory, can't find handle , it says.

Comment: Is this the unedited example?  And both instances are open at the same time?

Comment: OK. Figured it out. The problem was a stray `detach()` code, which'd detach the sharedMemory before the second instance could attach to it, hence no handle to attach to. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same problem. Make sure that QSharedMemory object still lives when second binary tries to attach. 
If you want to block ability to run 2 instances of same QT binary, just make QSharedMemory object using dynamic memory which will live until app exit.